# In an e-commerce site why the checkout card is often placed in right hand side...why not in left?

Tags: website-design, e-commerce, psychology, ux-integration

I visited over maximum e-commerce web site but they have a common thing is that the **check out page is always in right side of the page**. what is the **UX logic** / **mental model** / **cognitive science**  behind this? if i want to place it in left hand side, is it will be treated as wrong UX design?

Answer (score 3):

Almost everywhere in the world you turn pages from right to left, so in most cultures moving to the right side is associated with moving to the next page/stage. And moving to the left is associated with going back/to the previous page.

Comment: That’s only true for the people who write from left to right.

Comment: @bfontaine I did write that, didn't I?

Comment: Yes you did; but I think it’s better to explicitly write it instead of "almost everywhere in the world".

Comment: @bfontaine Agree, I should have written it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the language you’re familiar with.

People who write from left to right feel progress as something from left to right; the right represents what’s "after". People who write from right to left have the inverse expectation.

Most of what we put on the right in the Western world is on the left in the Arabic, Japanese, and Chinese ones. For example, iOS puts the "back" button on the right when used in the Arabic language.

#### Sources

- [Designing an Arabic UX: Usability & Arabic User Interfaces](http://uxbert.com/designing-an-arabic-user-experience-usability-arabic-user-interfaces/)
- [Designing for the Arab User — Basic Arabic UX for Business](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/designing-for-the-arab-user-basic-arabic-ux-for-business-6ff29d4c7c60)
- [Arabic, Japanese, and Chinese Layouts in User Interface and User Experience Design](https://yalantis.com/blog/japanese-chinese-and-arabic-layouts-in-user-interface-and-user-experience-design/)